# Creating a Spinner control in a Airplay Application

Tags: android, cross-platform

Can someone tell me how I can create a Spinner control using Airplay SDK for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is called CIwUIPickerView; here is an example of using it.

http://www.airplaysdk.com/node/487